# Determining the BIg O notation of this loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
for(i=0;i<n;i+=2) {
  for(j=1;j<=n;j*=2) {
      printf(“%d,%d\n”,i,j);
    }
}
```

What would be the Big O notation of this loop?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer loop will do `n/2` iterations, and each inner loop will do `lg_2(n)` iterations.

The overall running time should be `O(n*lgn)` (here I use `lg` to represent log base 2).